# VMware ESXi 6.0 and Openstack

Tags: vmware-esxi, openstack

I have a private cloud of Openstack running KVM compute. I'm looking to add other hypervisors into the Openstack private cloud as well. Namely, vmware and hyper-V. I know VMware has been researching Openstack integration for some time. My question is, does ESXi 6.0 support some level of northbound Openstack out of the box? How would I put ESXi and Hyper-V under the Openstack umbrella?

Answer (score 3):

ESXi doesn't support the OpenStack API directly. There's [VMware Integrated OpenStack](http://vmware.com/go/openstack) (VIO)... although I don't think it's supported to use other hypervisors with this.

If you want to use vSphere as a backend for OpenStack without VIO, this is fortunately documented [here](http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/config-reference/content/vmware.html) but it looks like this works via vCenter only.

If you can't use vCenter because you want to use the free ESXi hypervisor: I don't see any advantages over KVM in that case.